# Python File iterator running multiple times

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, word2vec, listiterator

I am using gensim to create a word2vec model of a sample file I have in a directory. I followed a tutorial online, which reads files in a directory and processes it line by line. My sample file has 9 lines in it. But this code gives my the same lines 9 times. Can someone please explain what's happening.

```
 class MySentences(object):
     def __init__(self, dirname):
         self.dirname = dirname   

     def __iter__(self): 
         for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
             for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                 print os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)
                 yield line.split() 

 sentences = MySentences('/fakepath/Folder')
```

Details:
Suppose filename contains 3 lines like

```
hi how are you.
I am fine.
I am good.
```

`line.split()` should give me: `['hi','how','are','you']` only once. But this happens 3 times so I get the above list thrice instead of once. If the total sentences are 5, then it returns the line 5 times.

Comment: What is `line` in `line.split()`? How is it initialized?

Comment: For every line in the file. it's Declared in the for loop

Comment: So, `'fakepath/filename.txt'` is the `dirname`? It looks like a file name to me, not a directory name.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, It is the dirname. I've editied it

Comment: I actually tried your code (Python 2.7.3.), and it works as expected.

Comment: It should work fine because I've followed a tutorial for this. I don't know what's wrong. It's running the code in _iter_ () 3 times (Or whatever line count is in a file). That's weird

Comment: My file only has two words viz Hello Hi. The output I'm getting is
hello

hi
hello

hi
hello

hi
hello

hi
hello

hi
hello

hi

Comment: Does your folder have multiple copies of your file in it? Otherwise, it's not clear what is happening. Can you show the code that iterates on `sentences`?

Comment: No there's only one file. The code is in the iter method.

Comment: You misunderstand me about what code you should show. You need to show how `sentences` is used. What you've provided doesn't iterate the object at all. Are you using a `for` loop? Are you passing `sentences` as an argument to some function? You seem to be expecting a different outcome than you're getting, but all of that is happening elsewhere, not in the code you've shown, so we can't help you with it. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should figure out what you are trying to do. The `class MySentences` takes a directory as parameter and create a object `sentences` with a generator in it. So the `sentences` has a generator contains all lines in all the files in the directory.

For example:

```
for line in sentences:
    print(line)
```

you will get a lot of lists with words as a element(I have removed the print statement that prints path) . Which is:

```
['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you.']
```

`['I', 'am', 'fine.']`

`['I', 'am', 'good.']`

Comment: Yes, but it prints the above 3 lists 6 times. So
['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you.']
['I', 'am', 'fine.']
['I', 'am', 'good.'] is printed six times.

Comment: Could you try it without the `print(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname))`, The code works fine in my computer.

Comment: And your print code is? Could you show us the code?

Comment: Surely, Can you please put a 'print line' statement in iter above yeild line.split() and tell what is printed? Does it print the lines in the file only once or multiple times?. Appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: If you add the print statement above the `yield line.split()` , it will print the `path` plus the `filename` as many time as how many lists in the `sentences`.

Comment: Oh, so it is actually correct that it prints it multiple times?. I didn't understand how it works, sorry!

Comment: Oh..Thanks a lot. This was really frustrating me!